# java/ angular project sonar multi language support

Tags: sonarqube

Java8 - angular2 project.

using following maven plugin, sonar cube version 6.7.1

```
org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603
```

my project is using java/angular code written in .ts.

can i set multi language in sonar.language=java,ts property ? seems to me does not work and throws an error "java,ts" not a plugin

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried leaving `sonar.language` blank? According to the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters),

> If not set, a multi-language analysis will be triggered.

Please ensure your `sonar.sources` property covers the required source directories. You can also use `sonar.exclusions` to filter sources you don't need analyzed.

More info on this topic: https://blog.sonarsource.com/at-long-last-sonarqube-is-a-true-polyglot/

Comment: it does, but i want only java,ts to be trigger

Comment: in order to trigger mutli language simply remove this property and multi language analyzer will work.

Comment: I suppose you could try setting `sonar.sources` to the paths of only Java and TS code, or use `sonar.exclusions` to exclude non-Java and non-TS sources.

Comment: @Vasan it would be great if you updated your answer with the contents of your comment. :-D

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam Done!

Comment: i am using maven plugin which does not required sonar.sources directory to set.

Comment: How about setting `sonar.exclusions`?

Comment: yes i have exclusions set already as property in pom.file **/*.js and **/*.js.map